# RODBC unable to insert records to the oracle table one row at a time

Tags: r, oracle

I need to insert rows to oracle table one row at a time. If duplicates, due to PK set up, it will not be inserted. I need to reject insertion of duplicate rows to the db table.

I am doing this using RODBC and even there no duplicate values after 7:00PM on the table, not able to insert the records to the table, after 7:00PM. Dat data frame has values before and 7PM and after 7PM. But the destination oracle table does not have any values after 7PM. Any ideas, how else I can implement this to make sure values are inserted to the table one row at a time?

```
tryCatch({

  ch=odbcConnect("<id>",pwd = "<password>")
  sqlSave(ch,dat, tablename="<tablename>", rownames=FALSE, append=TRUE, fast=FALSE)
  },error = function(e) {
    print(e)
  })
  odbcClose(ch)
```

I get this error:

```
<simpleError in sqlSave(ch, dat, tablename = "<tablename>", rownames = FALSE,     append = TRUE, fast = FALSE): un
able to append to table '<tablename'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about this solution but open to any other solution if faster.

This is how I do to process one record at a time and insert inot the db. If duplicate records, that duplicate record will be rejected and R will continue on the next record:

```
for (k in 1:nrow(dat)) 
  {

    j<-dat[k,]

         tryCatch({

                  ch=odbcConnect("<id>",pwd = "<password>")
                  sqlSave(ch,j, tablename="<TableName>", rownames=FALSE, append=TRUE)
               },error = function(e) {
          print(e)
             })
}

 odbcClose(ch)
```